# I have 3 ArrayList and i want to put the values into the table of the SQLite database? i tried the below code but the activity is not opening

Tags: android, sqlite

```
     public class ques1 extends AppCompatActivity {
        SQLiteDatabase sql2;
        TextView txtv2;
        RadioButton rb1,rb2;
        Button btn2;
        Cursor c;
        String Ans="";
```

these are my 3 array list

```
       @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ques1);

 ArrayList<String> q = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    q.add("1.who is the fastest man on Earth?");
    q.add("2.how many days are there in a leap year?");
    q.add("3.what is the national animal of India");

    ArrayList<String> options1 = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    options1.add("Nikhil sudan");
    options1.add("365");
    options1.add("Lion");

    ArrayList<String> options2 = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    options2.add("Usain Bolt");
    options2.add("366");
    options2.add("Tiger");

   ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    answer.add("Usain BOlt");
    answer.add("365");
    answer.add("Tiger");
```

and this how i am inserting it into my table

```
    sql2 = openOrCreateDatabase("ddb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    sql2.execSQL("create table if not exists bank(question varchar,option1 varchar,option2 varchar,answ varchar)");

    for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++){
        sql2.execSQL("insert into bank values('" + q.get(i) + "','" + options1.get(i) + "','" + options2.get(i) + "','"+answer.get(i)+"')");
    }
```

and the raw query to add the question and options to my android activity and submit button to check the value of text of radio buttons with the **Ans**

```
    c=sql2.rawQuery("Select * from bank where q="+q.get(1).charAt(1),null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    txtv2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("question")));
    rb1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("option1")));
    rb2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("option2")));
    Ans=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("answ"));

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rb1.isChecked()){
                if (rb1.getText().equals(Ans)){
                    Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"Right answer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"wrong choice",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (rb2.isChecked()){
                if (rb1.getText().equals(Ans)){
                    Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"right Ans",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"Wrong choice",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

my log(updated) :

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.nikhil.dingdong, PID: 26739
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nikhil.dingdong/com.nikhil.dingdong.ques1}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from bank where question=.
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                      Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from bank where question=.
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                                         at com.nikhil.dingdong.ques1.onCreate(ques1.java:67)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)

Comment: Please add your complete code which shows what actually you want to do.

Comment: My activity is crashing...i don't know why.I don't see any errors.
Basically i have a text box and 2 radio buttons .
i have made a database for questions and options...i want the question and options from the database into the textview and radio buttons....and then check whether selected radio-button value is correct  or not

Comment: Upload your complete code and even your logs.I'll see if I can help.

Comment: check whether u can help

Comment: simple typo in your answer list.

Answer (score 0):

First correct your answer's arraylist so it will not give arrayindexoutofboundexception

```
ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>(3);
answer .add("Usain BOlt");
answer .add("365");
answer .add("Tiger");
```

Edit as below:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (rb1.isChecked()){
            if (rb1.getText().equals(Ans)){
                Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"Right answer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"wrong choice",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (rb2.isChecked()){
            if (rb2.getText().equals(Ans)){
                Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"right Ans",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(ques1.this,"Wrong choice",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

In your rawQuery remove     .charAt(1)

Replace q=q.get(1) with question=q.get(1) in rawquery

Comment: But where have you written the code for opening any activity man?

Comment: I don't want to open a new activity...just want to Toast whether selected option is right or wrong

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nikhil.dingdong/com.nikhil.dingdong.ques1}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "1.who" (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from bank where question=1.who is the fastest man on Earth?